# Is there closed formula to calculate the probability of beta distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Part of my investigation of the properties of the beta distribution, I was trying to figure if for $X\sim Beta(a,b)$ is there a closed formula for $P(X>x)$, $P(X<x)$ and $P(X=x)$? For example, if $X\sim\exp(\lambda)$ then we know that $P(X >a)=e^{-\lambda a}$ and $P(X\leq a)=1-e^{-\lambda a}$. Is there something similar for beta distribution?

Answer (score 1):

In general, we need [a special function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) for $P(X\le x)$. However, if $a$ and/or $b$ is a positive integer, we can obtain a closed-form solution (indeed, if both are positive integers it's a polynomial). Suppose $a$ is an integer:$$\begin{align}\int_0^x(1-t)^{b-1}dt&=\frac{1-(1-x)^b}{b},\\\int_0^xt^{c+1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt&=\int_0^xt^c(1-t)^{b-1}dt-\int_0^xt^c(1-t)^bdt.\end{align}$$Further, the normalization constant that ensures probabilities sum to $1$ will still be a value of the Beta function. Suppose $a$ is an integer:$$\operatorname{B}(1,\,b)=\frac1b,\,\frac{\operatorname{B}(c+1,\,b)}{\operatorname{B}(c,\,b)}=\frac{c}{b+c}.$$